# Use GLM in R to see if sex ratio varies by group

Tags: r, glm

I have a bunch of data on how things developed in the laboratory. This involves different collection site information and different treatments.

My question here: Did the groupings (place and treatment) have an effect on the resulting sex ration of adult males to females? And can I figure this out with a GLM?

[I don't know how many of each sex I put in, it was random, some juveniles died during development and I only sexed the adults]

I followed along this tutorial where I used a GLM to investigate the sex ratios:
http://www.simonqueenborough.info/R/stats-basic/glm.html

Here is my data and code:

```
mo<-"Temp   Locality    Females Males
A   APR 88  110
B   APR 101 97
C   APR 85  94
A   ARS 65  69
B   ARS 57  78
C   ARS 54  76
A   RMO 103 90
B   RMO 97  101
C   RMO 82  78
A   RPV 89  92
B   RPV 98  86
C   RPV 64  76
A   SJU 66  63
B   SJU 57  66
C   SJU 16  17
A   TLC 45  46
B   TLC 41  43
C   TLC 27  44
A   TPN 25  20
B   TPN 22  25
C   TPN 16  22"

data <- read.table(text=mo, header = TRUE)
y<-cbind(data$Males,data$Females)
model<-glm(y~data$Temp+data$Locality, family=binomial)
summary(model)

#results of summary (model)
Call:                       
glm(formula = y ~ sexy$Temp + sexy$Locality, family = binomial)                     

Deviance Residuals:                         
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max                         
-0.8231  -0.5549  -0.2398   0.5038   1.2954                         

Coefficients:                       
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)                       
(Intercept)       0.03839    0.09885   0.388    0.698                       
sexy$TempB        0.03032    0.09093   0.333    0.739                       
sexy$TempC        0.14538    0.09818   1.481    0.139                       
sexy$LocalityARS  0.14092    0.13098   1.076    0.282                       
sexy$LocalityRMO -0.13872    0.11938  -1.162    0.245                       
sexy$LocalityRPV -0.07783    0.12213  -0.637    0.524                       
sexy$LocalitySJU -0.01914    0.14600  -0.131    0.896                       
sexy$LocalityTLC  0.07243    0.15286   0.474    0.636                       
sexy$LocalityTPN -0.03022    0.19444  -0.155    0.877
```

From both model summary, I found no significant differences in sex ratio by temperature or locality. Is this real? Is the GLM appropriate or is there another method?

Comment: Looks like a statistics question rather than a programming question. You should ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, will head over there!

Answer (score 0):

Not a question for here... but I'll answer it anyways.

Your model doesn't make sense. A binomial model should have a 1 or 0 dependent variable. The question with a binomial model would be "for each individual observation of a female or male (1 or 0), does temperature or locality influence the probability that a female or male is observed". So instead of modeling the # of females vs. the # of males, you model the probability that at any given point a female or male will be observed based on the influence of temperature/locality.

You could model ratio explicitly by creating a dependent variable of males/female or vice versa and use that in a linear regression model. But that would probably be ill-advised. Modeling proportions in a linear framework can be anti-conservative particularly if proportions are skewed close to 1. But if your ratios are well distributed between 0:1 and not skewed close to 1, then it might not be that awful (though it's still a bit of not great way to model a ratio).

I would consider reformatting your data so you can actually model it within a binomial framework, like your original idea. The modeling logic of binomial model is relatively close to your intended question (what influences the probability that I will observe a male or female)? Just make a data frame that has 1 observation of Temperature and 1 observation of Locality for each observation of gender (coded as a 1 or 0 (e.g., male == 1, female == 0)) and model that in a binomial/logistic framework.

You could do a 2nd binomial model of dead vs. not dead if you want to see what temp/locality diffs. influenced development to adulthood.

ALSO - you need to contrast code your categorical predictors if you have any interest in interpreting the effect directions, etc. of different temp/localities.